# Choosing which Record Layout to embed in Lightning Record Page

Tags: lightning

Lightning Record Page allow to embed classic record layout, which one defines through the classic layout editor.

How do I choose which one of my classic layout I embed in a specific Lightning Page? Is it handled by the page layout assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's handled by the page layout assignments, which is a matrix of Record Types and Profiles.